# How to change Mach-O Type for a pod using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, mach-o

Task: Change the `Mach-O Type` for an individual pod (single library).

What changes need to be done in the `Podfile` so that I can set the `Mach-O Type` of my choice for any target in the `Pods.xcodeproj`?

Currently, it is set from the `podspec` file of that pod. **Is there a way I can define this in Podfile?**

In my project, I need to use it as a target `static library`. I can change it manually but, since we're using git and pods folder is excluded from the source code. It gets overridden. Also, we are using CI/CD so, we can not rely on manually changing it every time.

Why not use dynamic? Well, there is one particular library that does not allow the code to generate the code coverage. Changing the `Mach-O Type` to static solves our problem.

[image]

Comment: You can set all pods to static with `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

Comment: @PaulBeusterien What if I only want to make a few selected pod static?